# How to find when/whether a kernel bug patch is going to make it officially into 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, kernel, nfs

```
Bug: unable to handle page fault for address: ffffffffffffffb0. Upstream commit 29fe839976266bc7c55b927360a1daae57477723
```

https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/5/18/1162
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/29fe839976266bc7c55b927360a1daae57477723

Running Ubuntu 5.3 gcp kernel on Google Compute Engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question can be difficult to answer, the actual answer being "I don't know" how long it will take.

However you can look up the actual included commit and observe:

```
doug@s18:~/temp-k-git/linux$ git tag --contains 29fe83997626
v5.7
v5.7-rc6
v5.7-rc7
v5.8-rc1
```

So, it was only  included as of 5.7-rc6, a few weeks ago. More important is to notice that `stable` was copied on the commit:

```
Cc: stable@vger.kernel.org # v4.20+
```

meaning it has already been flagged for backport to earlier kernels. Typically that takes maybe a couple of months, faster depending on the urgency, but then it would take further time for distribution releases of linux (i.e. Ubuntu) to include it in their kernel updates.

EDIT: Already backported to [kernel 5.4.42](https://lwn.net/Articles/820973/) on 2020.05.20.
EDIT2: [Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1879759) (Focal)

Comment: Thank you!  Very helpful.